# Restrict the Viewable Area in a shared Excel Document

Tags: excel, passwords, restriction

I have been searching all morning for a way to restrict the viewable area in a shared excel document. I have found  how to restrict opening the workbook as a whole and how to restrict editable areas by password, and a few that allude to restricting visible areas but not very clear.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide all the cells or columns manually and then protect the Worksheet.

1. Click on the column `A` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +
2. Hide the columns ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> )
3. Protect the worksheet with your desired permission

Now whenever soembody tries to view the Worksheet, they need to unprotect it first via password:

[image]

> Obviously, you don't have to hide entire worksheet, perhaps just some parts depending on your specific needs